# How to define an instantiated React component in a Typescript interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, react-component

First of, I'm new to both React JS and Typescript. But basically I have a function which takes an object by interface:

```
interface ModalContents {
    component: React.Component,
    ...
}

export default function buildModal(contents : ModalContents){
    ...
    render() {
       return (
           <Modal>
               <ModalHeader>
                   ...
               </ModalHeader>
               <ModalBody>{contents.component}</ModalBody>
               <ModalFooter>
                   ...
               </ModalFooter>
           </Modal>
       );
    }
    ...
}
```

The interface is among others expecting an instantiated component which is to be inserted inside the `render` method. Now I'm using the function like this:

```
class ExampleModal extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        ...
    }
  render() {
    return (
        <Container id="example-modal">
            ...
        </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default buildModal({component: <ExampleModal ... />, ...});
```

But for the component part of the object I pass to `buildModal` I am getting this error by VSC:

```
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'Component<{}, {}, any>'.
```

My goal is to get a rendered result like this:

`<Modal>
       <ModalHeader>
           ...
       </ModalHeader>
       <ModalBody>
            <Container id="example-modal">
                ...
            </Container></ModalBody>
       <ModalFooter>
           ...
       </ModalFooter>
   </Modal>`

I'm aware that I could just pass the `ComponentClass` for `ExampleModal` instead and instantiate it inside `buildModal`, but I think this would make it unnecessarily cumbersome to pass the Props and States to the component.

So how can I do this? What is the right class to use inside of the interface? Is it even possible, or did I get something wrong about the concept here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExampleModal` is React *component*, `<ExampleModal ... />` is React *element*.

Considering that `buildModal` should accept an element, it should be:

```
interface ModalContents {
    component: React.ReactElement,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Close one, it didn't quite work until I added the generic types like this: `component: React.ReactElement<{}, any>`. Thank you :)